# How to tell the association direction of two nominal variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

For example, no offense to anyone, I'd like to test if smoking is related to gender. Both smoking and gender are nominal variables.

I know I can use the Chi-Squared test to know **if** there's a relationship. But what test method to use to know the **direction** of the association? In other words, I want to know whether male or female persons tend to be smokers. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: You can look at the phi ($\phi$) coefficient, which is related to both the chi-squared statistic and to the correlation between the binary variables; if $\phi>0$ then the two "1" levels to occur together more than at independence (also the two "0" levels). If $\phi<0$ then the "1" level of one variable tends to associate with the "0" level of the other. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the Spearman correlation, which handles ordered values. It would work if you have smoking categories like none, 1 pack, 2 packs etc. The correlation coefficient's sign tells you if the association is positive or negative. Note that it only tells you if there is a monotonic increasing/decreasing relationship between the two variables. Unlike the Pearson correlation, Spearman won't tell you how linear it is.

Spearman correlation is often used for Likert scales, which are ordinal data.

If you wanted to calculate effect size and handle covariates, you can use Ordinal Logistic Regression: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/

Example code for Spearman Correlation, where I've purposely created more males for smoker and fewer females for non-smoker:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='white')

smoker_data = (['s']*50 + ['ns'] * 50)

gender_data = \
    random.choices(['m','f'], k=50, weights=[3,1]) \
    + random.choices(['m','f'], k=50, weights=[1,3])

df = pd.DataFrame([smoker_data, gender_data], index=['smoker', 'gender']).T



corr, p = spearmanr(
    smoker_data,
    gender_data,
)

print(p) # 7.044e-14
print(corr) # 0.66

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

sns.stripplot(
    x=df['smoker'],
    y=df['gender'],
    jitter=0.3,
    ax=ax,    
)

fig.savefig('plot.png')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But can Spearman handle nominal variables? Sorry, I should have made it clear: the smoking category is just smoker or non-smoker, not how many packs they smoke.

Comment: Added example code to show that one can use nominal variables